# how to use tidyjson inside dplyr

Tags: json, r, dplyr

I have dataframe, called `data_df`, which has one column which contain json string, column name is `json_response`.

I want access very specific key-value from it. Example of one of json string as follows. I want to know how many times success is true in string.

```
x = "[{\"s\":\"D\",\"success\":true,\"start.time\":\"2016-01-27 19:27:27\",\"stop.time\":\"2016-01-27 19:27:30\",\"status_code\":200,\"called\":true,\"milliseconds\":3738.6858,\"_row\":\"DataX\"},{\"s\":\"C\",\"success\":true,\"start.time\":\"2016-01-27 19:27:30\",\"stop.time\":\"2016-01-27 19:27:32\",\"status_code\":200,\"called\":true,\"milliseconds\":1815.1433,\"_row\":\"Clarity\"}]"
```

If I only want to use `tidyjson`, I can do it as follows, which works as I want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyjson) 
x %>% gather_array %>% 
    spread_values(called = jstring("called")) %>% 
    summarize(x = sum(called == "TRUE"))
```

Now if I want to do it for whole column, how should I do it? I don't want to use a loop.

Following is my code which I tried to use.

```
data_df %>% 
    transmute(
              test =  json_response %>% gather_array %>% 
                  spread_values(called = jstring("called")) %>% 
                  summarize(x = sum(called=="TRUE")) 
    )
```

Following is the error I got when I ran the above code:

> ```
> Error: not compatible with STRSXP
> ```

Comment: As the error says, it is not compatible

Comment: Is it due to date in json format ?

Comment: It could be one of the formats not supported within the transmute

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `tidyjson` you can use `rjson` combined with `dplyr` in a way like this:

```
data_df$test <- data_df %>% rowwise %>% 
      do(test = .$json_response %>% as.character %>% fromJSON %>% sapply(`[[`, "called") %>% sum) %>% 
      as.data.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyjson` for this, simply convert `data_df` into a `tbl_json` object, and then proceed as before:

```
data_df %>% 
  as.tbl_json(json.column = "json_response") %>%
  # track each document if you don't already have an ID
  mutate(rownum = 1:n()) %>% 
  gather_array %>%           
  # use jlogical for correct type
  spread_values(success = jlogical("success")) %>%  
  group_by(rownum) %>% 
  summarize(num.successes = sum(success))
```